# Fatal error: Class 'Elementor\Widget_Base' not found

Tags: php, elementor

I am trying a to add a new widget from my plugin to elementor. I have followed the documentation to how to create an elementor widget: https://developers.elementor.com/creating-a-new-widget/

But problem is its not working..
No#1. When i am using autoload its not showing any error
No#2. But when i am using `require_once` its shows a fatal error: `Fatal error: Class 'Elementor\Widget_Base' not found`

### My widget code

```
<?php
namespace WPEVENTCAL\extensions\elementor;

class widget extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {

    public function get_name() {
        return 'Aembed';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return __( 'oEmbed', 'plugin-name' );
    }

    public function get_icon() {
        return 'fa fa-code';
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return [ 'basic' ];
    }

    protected function _register_controls() {

        $this->start_controls_section(
            'content_section',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Content', 'plugin-name' ),
                'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'url',
            [
                'label' => __( 'URL to embed', 'plugin-name' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                'input_type' => 'url',
                'placeholder' => __( 'https://your-link.com', 'plugin-name' ),
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();

    }

    protected function render() {

        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

        $html = wp_oembed_get( $settings['url'] );

        echo '<div class="oembed-elementor-widget">';

        echo ( $html ) ? $html : $settings['url'];

        echo '</div>';

    }   

}
```

### My folder structure

`-Main plugin file
    -extension
        -elementor
            -widget.php
    - index.php`

In `index.php` i am calling `require_once( 'extensions/elementor/widget.php' );`

It throws that error : `Fatal error: Class 'Elementor\Widget_Base' not found`

But when i use autoload function in index it doesn't gives any error neither shows widget

```
use WPEVENTCAL\extensions\elementor\index;
function autoload($class = '') {
    if (!strstr($class, 'WPEVENTCAL')) {
        return;
    }
    $result = str_replace('WPEVENTCAL\\', '', $class);
    $result = str_replace('\\', '/', $result);
    require $result . '.php';
}
```

what may be the problem>?

Comment: The problem is in finding Elementor\Widget_Base, are you sure you have it loaded via autoloader? do you have a main autoloader in your app?

Comment: @Oras When its loaded via autoloader its not being loaded but when i use `require_once` it loads and shows that fatal error

Answer (score 2):

At the start, the Elementor class will not be loaded. So use the init WordPress hooks, in that function require the file and create an object as suggested in the below code.

```
function load_elementor_widget() {
    require('your-php-code-that-extends-elementor-widget-class');
    
    \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register( new \Elementor\My_Widget_1() );
}
add_action('init', 'load_elementor_widget')
```

Answer (score 0):

Better approach :

check if the widget base class exist the run widget class

```
if (class_exists('Widget_Base')){
    class widget extends Widget_Base {

        public function get_name() {
            return 'Aembed';
        }

        public function get_title() {
            return __( 'oEmbed', 'plugin-name' );
        }

        public function get_icon() {
            return 'fa fa-code';
        }

        public function get_categories() {
            return [ 'basic' ];
        }

        protected function _register_controls() {

            $this->start_controls_section(
                'content_section',
                [
                    'label' => __( 'Content', 'plugin-name' ),
                    'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
                ]
            );

            $this->add_control(
                'url',
                [
                    'label' => __( 'URL to embed', 'plugin-name' ),
                    'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                    'input_type' => 'url',
                    'placeholder' => __( 'https://your-link.com', 'plugin-name' ),
                ]
            );
            $this->end_controls_section();
        }

        protected function render() {
            $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
            $html = wp_oembed_get( $settings['url'] );
            echo '<div class="oembed-elementor-widget">';
            echo ( $html ) ? $html : $settings['url'];
            echo '</div>';

        }
    }
}
```